# Starting Intent.ACTION_SEND always return resultCode 0

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm sharing an image from my application by starting Intent.ACTION_SEND with image msg.setType("image/png") using startActivityForResult(). The call works perfectly and displays the desired activity chooser.

But when I get back to onActivityResult() the resultCode is always 0. To display my UI correctly I need to know if the user sent / shared the picture or cancelled the operation. Is there any way for me to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the resultcode needs to be set in the acticty which u launch to send the image. In the acitivity which is used to send the image set positive result before finishing the activity

Comment: Is there any contract how these result codes should be handled? For example in case of default gmail client I have no idea if user sent the email or cancelled. On the other hand the user might select to share my image through Twitter or Facebook. I have no control over those applications and their activities. I was just hoping there would be some spec that required sending applications to return certain codes when they finnish.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#constants if u see here the result each resultcode has a meaning. The app you are calling should follow this to let other apps use it effectively.

Comment: @juhani Did you manage to figure this out?  I just read the link Varun posted and it confirms what I'm seeing - e.g. it always returns RESULT_CANCELED?